# How can i connect two parallel UPS that sharing the same load?

Tags: ups

I have a critical load .I want to connect two parallel UPS that sharing the same output, how can i control them??

it's hard and danger to turn on both of them and synchronizing them. i want a controller name or a way to control them.

the controller must turn on one of them in a time and switching if any interutpion in the second UPS occured without disconnicting the load.

Comment: No, you have redundant power supplies in your device, each connected to a different UPS.

Comment: Can you tell me what i supposed to do? what is redundant? 

I assume that the Two UPS systems It will work parallel redundant and will be controlled by static transfer switch. Am i right?

Comment: Enterprise-grade servers, switches, routers, etc. that are made for up time and availability can have multiple, redundant power supplies. You connect each power supply to an independent power circuit, and you can have a separate UPS on each circuit. If a power supply or circuit fails, then your device is still up with no interruption.

Answer (score 2):

Am I understanding correctly that you are wanting to protect against UPS failure?

You're thinking about it the wrong way. The way you protect against this kind of failure is your load must have redundant power supplies, which allows one supply to safely fail when the UPS that one is connected to fails. If your load does not have this capability then hopefully you can have two of whatever it is in some kind of highly available cluster/configuration to allow one unit to fail completely.

Comment: I want to feed the load with UPS, but the load is critical so i have to add another ups to feed the load if any failure happen in the first UPS.

It will work parallel redundant and will be controlled by static transfer switch. 
Am i right?